# How to show Holidays where all branches for specific Person are in Holiday?

Tags: sql-server

I have following tables:

```
Table @t1 (Specific Person brnaches)
 BranchID
    10
    11

Table @t2 
BranchID   Holiday
  10    2018-01-01
  12    2018-01-01
  10    2018-01-05
  11    2018-01-05

Table @t3 (Holidays)
Holiday
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
2018-01-05   

declare  @t1  table
(
BranchID int
)
declare @t2 table
(
BranchID int,
Holiday date
)
declare @t3 table
(
Holiday date
)
insert into @t1
values(10),(11)

insert into @t2
values (10,'2018-01-01'),(12,'2018-01-01'),(10,'2018-01-05'),(11,'2018-01-05')

insert into @t3
values ('2018-01-01'),('2018-01-02'),('2018-01-03'),('2018-01-04'),('2018-01-05')
```

Result from @t3 must be '2018-01-05'
Because both 10,11 BranchID in table @t2 in  '2018-01-05' are in Holiday

How to impelement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that you don't need to use table `@T3` here, you can try like following to get the desired output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Holiday FROM
(
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Holiday ORDER BY Holiday) AS HC
  FROM @t2 BH 
  WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM  @T1 T1 WHERE T1.BranchID=BH.BranchID 
      -- Put condition like AND PersonId=@PersonId to fetch all the branches of the user.
    )
) T
WHERE T.HC = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @T1) --Total branch count for a person
```

**Output**

```
+------------+
| Holiday    |
+------------+
| 2018-01-05 |
+------------+
```